# Django queryset for intersecting ManyToMany relations fields

Tags: django, database, django-models, orm

I have a difficult problem, I'm trying to select models related to each other with ManyToMany relations, depending on the intersection of the models present on each ManyToMany fields. I tried to achieve this with F() but without success, I don't think I'm skilled enough about DB/ORM to solve this.

Here is a example:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    want_private = models.ManyToManyField('User')

class User(AbstractUser):
    events = models.ManyToManyField(Event, related_name='users')
```

First I'd like to select events from a set of users, e.g. those starting with "a":

```
users_a = User.objects.filter(username_startswith="a")
```

So the queryset should be:

```
Event.objects.filter(users=users_a)
```

When it gets complicated is that I would like to:

- **exclude** events where a user is at the same time in the `users` field of the event, in the `want_private` field of the event, and in the `users_a` queryset.
- **include** events where a user is in at the same time in `users` field of the event, **not** in the `want_private` field of the event, and in the `users_a` queryset.

Do anyone by any chance have an idea to solve this?

Thank you very much,

Camille.

Comment: Can you clarify how `User.events` is related to `Event.want_private`. For the data you want to store, would it ever be possible for a user to be in `Event.want_private` but *not* in `Event.users`?

Comment: Hi @solarissmoke, indeed I should have mentioned this, no it is not possible for a `User` to be in `want_private` but not in `users`. However the opposite is possible, a user can be in `users` but not in `want_private`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above it seems like a user can be associated with an event, and their association is either public or private (I'm interpreting what `want_private` might mean here). If that is the case, then I suggest you alter your data structure, and store this information in a [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). Something like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    # Remove want_private from here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    events = models.ManyToManyField(Event, related_name='users', through=UserEvent)

class UserEvent(models.Model):
    """ Through model between event and user. Store want_private here."""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    want_private = models.BooleanField()  # This is now a boolean field
```

How this works is explained in the documentation I've linked to above.

Now, your event query becomes much simpler:

```
Event.objects.filter(users__username__startswith='a', userevent__wants_private=False)
```

This will give you all events where *at least one user is associated with that event, and their association is not private*. If an event has users falling in both categories, then this query will include that event.

I've made some assumptions here about the meaning of `want_private`. If `want_private` is essentially an additional flag that goes with a user's association with an event, then this through-model is the right data stucture.

Comment: Thanks a lot @solarissmoke, I didn't think about `through`, it's a very interesting lead. And I assume it's within the scope of my skills. I will try to make it work on my side. Thanks again!